# MySQL Database PHP Specific Rows

Tags: php, mysql

My current code is this:

```
   <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("stevie.heliohost.org","rbxdataa_Art","mydata123art");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


mysqli_select_db($con, "rbxdataa_Data");
$Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
$GetType=$_GET["Type"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC";
$sql_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run)){
   echo $sql_row['EventId'].'<br>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As I am currently very new to PHP and MySQL, I have no idea why this code will not work. I am also confused as to how I would make it echo only the top ($Amount) as determined by how large the "EventId" value is.
My intent is to gather the [$Amount] highest rows in the table with the EventType $GetType.
I am aware of SQL Injection vulnerability, however for my purposes this does not affect me.
Error:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 4"

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: have you any records in EventRecord table in desired EventType

Comment: can you show EventRecord attributes ?

Comment: Is their any row for amount? Paste structure of EventRecord.

Comment: If you want to sort the result based on highest amount then change the order clause and do it on the basis of amount field

Comment: I'm not receiving any error.

Comment: 1 EventId int(7)  2 PlayerName char(100) latin1_general_ci  3 EventType char(30) latin1_general_ci  4 Value char(110) latin1_general_ci  5 Time char(100) latin1_general_ci –

Comment: Why delete the content of your post? Really bad practice... Never do this again.

Comment: I have rolled your edit back. That is not an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have a normal code, may be you have no any rows in DataBase with requested `EventType` ?

At second: you have SQL Injection vulnerability. Use [PDO and Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead your mysqli_query code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the row with the max eventid, you need do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(EventId)  FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType';
```

is not necessary order by eventid when u can get the max using MAX(An AGGREGATION FUNCTION)

P.D: you can add more attributes in select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
if you need **highest amount** with EventType.

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(amount_field) FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType';
```

Comment: I need not just the highest one, the highest [whatever the value of $Amount is]

Comment: Do you need summation of amount base on EventType?

Answer (score 0):

If you want record sorted based on amount from highest to lowest then order by amount desc. (if you have amount column in table)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("Removed for Privacy");
mysqli_select_db($con, "Removed") or die(mysqli_error());

$Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
$GetType=$_GET["Type"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY amount DESC";
$sql_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run)){
   echo $sql_row['EventId'].'<br>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```